# HttpClient Enviar parametros en un Cliente Web Api Rest

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Me encargaron crear un cliente de muestra para que el usuario final consuma el Web APi rest que se construyó; Se tiene este método donde toma la autenticación con Json Web Token:

```
    public static void ConsumirServicio()
    {
        try
        {
            // Usamos HttpClient.
            using (HttpClient MockClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                MockClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "mytoken");
                var response = MockClient.GetAsync(urlConsumir).Result;
                resultadoServicio = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
```

En el `urlConsumir` se encuentra la cadena
`http://localhost:24175/api/ConsultasGP/ConsultaPuertos?fecha=2018-01-01` que lee para hacer la consulta la cual tiene parametros en Uri [FromUri] y en el Body [FromBody] este es el metodo que se expone:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult ConsultaPuertos([FromBody] List<PuertosGP> 
lstPuertosGP, [FromUri] DateTime fecha)
```

la pregunta es: como envio los parametros del body al urlConsumir?

Comment: Ya lo estabas haciendo, en las otras preguntas, estabas enviando parámetros en el body, ¿a qué te refieres exactamente? La pregunta como está, no se entiende puesto que hay pocos datos para reproducir tu escenario.

Comment: Antes de comenzar a crear un cliente C# para consumir un Web API de ASP.NET, debes conocer, saber y estudiar cómo construirlo. Te recomiendo leas este artículo con detenimiento y calma: [Cómo crear un cliente C# para un Web API de ASP.NET](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/10/29/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-cliente-c-para-un-web-api-de-aspnet-core-iii)

Comment: @RafaelAcosta tu blog es lo que buscaba!! Solo que no Use Asp.net Core sino ver 4.6

Comment: @fredyfx es parecida a las otras preguntas solo que en esas era usando POSTMAN ahora es hacer un Cliente (HttpClient Client = new HttpClient()) y debo pasar los parametros que van en el body

Comment: @ger: Da igual en que framework esté construido el Web API, a ti lo que te interesa en saber como utilizar el `HttpClient` para construir el cliente que lo consuma.

Comment: Ese `HttpClient` sigue siendo el mismo para todo .net

Comment: por cierto @RafaelAcosta muy buen blog! date una vuelta por mi sitio http://fredyfx.com tengo un blog y una biblioteca de enlaces pública, espero sea tu agrado, gracias por colaborar con la comunidad, un abrazo :D

Comment: @fredyfx: Ok, así es, lo que interesa es aprender como definir el `HttpClient `.

Comment: @fredyfx: Que es eso de " una biblioteca de enlaces pública", y donde la tienes, me interesa.

Comment: En la parte de resources, en el menú de mi sitio web

Comment: @RafaelAcosta entonces coloca tu referencia a tu blog para marcarlo como respuesta, Probare con lo que explicas allí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En principio, debes de tener claro como construir un `HttpClient` para poder consumir un Web API Rest, independientemente de la tecnología en la que esté desarrollado el Web API (es un estándar).

Debes saber cómo añadir datos a la cabecera (`Headers`) de la petición (`Request`):

```
using (var request_ = new HttpRequestMessage())
{
    // ASIGNAMOS A LA CABECERA DE LA PETICIÓN EL TOKEN JWT.
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_bearerTokenJWT))
    request_.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _bearerTokenJWT);
}
```

Y cómo añadir datos al cuerpo (`Body`) de la petición:

```
using (var request_ = new HttpRequestMessage())
{
    // DEFINIMOS EL Content (CUERPO) CON EL OBJETO A ENVIAR SERIALIZADO.
    request_.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(miObjeto));
}
```

Por último, necesitas saber como configurar la respuesta (`Response`) que te devolverá el Web API.

```
// CONSTRUIMOS LA RESPUESTA (RESPONSE) //
var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
var responseText_ = await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

---

**Nota**: Para una información completa, te aconsejo leas este artículo: [Cómo crear un cliente C# para un Web API de ASP.NET](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/10/29/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-cliente-c-para-un-web-api-de-aspnet-core-iii)